# Get Last Time User Was Logged In

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to get the last time a user was logged into a WordPress site. Right now I am using this bit of code:

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'cd_set_last_login', 10, 2 );
function cd_set_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql') );
}
```

This gives me the last time I/the user logged in but if I logged in 5 minutes ago then this is what I get. I need last time a user was active, so if I was on the site 2 weeks ago I want to get that value and not the value from 5 minutes ago. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use a array

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'cd_set_last_login', 10, 2 );
function cd_set_last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
  if($arr= get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_login', true) ){
       $arr[]= current_time('mysql');
  } else {
       $arr= array(); // reset arr
       $arr[]= current_time('mysql');
  }
  update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', $arr );
}
```

I haven't checked this but you may have a problem saving a array into mysql, i think update_user_meta() will serialize the array automatically but if not you will need to use the functions `serialize()` and `unserialize()` to convert to a string /back to a array